# Jquery select by class alternatives

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two html elements(span and input) which represent the same user property. In my JQuery script I want to select both elements. The only way I found to do this is to specify different ids and to execute two queries

```
$("#span\\.firstName")
$("#input\\.firstName").
```

At the moment I am looking for another solution. I want to use class attribute (specify class firstName on span and input and then perform

```
$(".firstName")
```

), but CSS aren't ready and I don't know which classes
will be required, so I can't use it. Do you know, if exists any other solution to perform this selection, like with class attribute.

```
<td>
  <div>
     <span id="span.firstName">${user.firstName}</span>
     <span id="span.lastName">${user.lastName}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
     <span>First name</span><input id="input.firstName" value="${user.firstName}"/>
     <span>Last name</span><input id="input.lastName" value="${user.lastName}"/>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the dot `.`  in HTML elements ids

Comment: Well I deleted my answer to this question as your question is unclear and to be frank, getting downvotes on a valid answer is frankly ridiculous.

Comment: Dot in id is permit by HTML specification. I need to show hierarchy in id. Is any other variant to do this?

Comment: It is permitted yes but then you have to escape it in jQuery selectors with \\. Could you use another char such as _ ?

Comment: I have some names like bank_account_holder, therefore I need some other delimiter. But the question is if exists any other attribute to specify class of objects that don't influence on css appearance.

Comment: You don't have to use classes that are referenced in the CSS. You can use whatever classes you like.

Comment: @zeroflagL Can I use multiple classes on class element?

Comment: Yes -- in the class attribute you can specify all the classes you want

Comment: Thank you this solution is better than offered below. I didn't know that class attribute accepts several values.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do a selector like so:

```
$("[id*='firstName']") // this will give both span and input of firstName etc
```

**[`Official Document`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**

Comment: @Toni Toni Chopper, please tell me your reasoning for down voting this solution.

Comment: Then I'd love to know who has, this is ideal towards the scenario.

Comment: +1 for first to answer which gets upvote and you get down vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('[id*="firstName"]')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/atekw/)

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking for. And one more question which delimiter symbol can I use in id instead of dot symbol.

Comment: 13 minutes after the original answer, with the exact same code, and this one gets the credit... what?

Comment: @Chris Dixon Sorry I looked at the top. This is the solution that resolves my problem.

Comment: @mvb13: You can use the `_` or the `-`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). `$('#id1, #id2')`